# capture flow of execution in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

I am very new to Microsoft SQL server. I am wondering if it is possible to capture a trace of the sql query on a database executed from an external program while ignoring the actions caused by trigger.

I used SQL profiler and choose to capture the text content for the SP:StmtCompleted event. The result is very overwhelming and contains a lot of code that is specified in the trigger.

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Filter on `ObjectType` of `<> 21076` (You will need to select the "Show all columns" option to make it appear in the list)

[image: Profiler screenshot]